# Dialog creation and destruction loop increases memory usage

Tags: c, windows, memory-leaks, gtk, gtk3

I wrote a simple program module to ask a user for a profile name. To do that I create windoww with entry widget, and two buttons (Ok and Cancel) organized in a grid. When user enters a profile name that already exists it informs him of that fact by creating dialog with "ok" button, and after he presses it, it goes back to picking a profile name (the window was not hidden nor destroyed in the meantime). The problem is that when I create a profile, and then spam the ok button (by placing something heavy on enter key and going to make tea) on both profile name chooser and the dialog (making a simple loop with creation and destruction of a dialog) the memory usage of the program increases.

---

TL;DR
Simply creating and destroying gtk window (and dialog) seems to cause a memory leak. Leaving app in a loop made it increase it's memory usage by ~1900% (from 10mb to 200mb).

No, I didn't test for memory leaks using apps designed for it.
Yes, I've set G_SLICE=always-malloc.
Yes, there is another thread running in the background of the program (but I'm sure it doesn't cause any leaks)
I can post screens from Windows Performance Monitor if you want more info on what happens in the memory.

The question is - is it a memory leak caused by me, or is it GTK's fault (I heard it has a lazy policy of memory management, but after some time memory usage drops from 200mb to 140mb and stays there)?

Here's the code:

```
// This callback racts to the ok and cancel buttons. If input was correcs
// or the user pressed cancel it destroys the window. Else it show error
// prompt. The showing error prompt seems to be the problem here.
void pickNameButtCB(GtkWidget *button, gpointer *call)
{
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_widget_get_toplevel(button);
    if( *((char*)call) == 'k')
    {
        GList *entryBase = gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER(gtk_bin_get_child(GTK_BIN(window)))), *entry = entryBase;
        for(size_t i=g_list_length(entry); i>0 && !GTK_IS_ENTRY(entry->data); --i)
            entry = g_list_next(entry);
        if(gtk_entry_get_text_length(GTK_ENTRY(entry->data)) > 0)
        {
            const char *temp = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry->data));
            char path[266];
            strcpy(path, settingsDir);
            strcat(path, temp);
            strcat(path, ".prof");

            if(settProfExists(path))
            {
                g_list_free(entryBase);
                showError(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_MESSAGE_ERROR, "Profile with that name already exists!");
                return;
            }
            // nothing here executes as well
        }
        else
        {
            /** doesn't execute when the memory leak happens */
        }
        g_list_free(entryBase);
    }
    gtk_widget_destroy(window);
    gtk_main_quit();
}

void showError(GtkWindow *parent, GtkMessageType type, const char *str)
{
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_message_dialog_new(parent, GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT, type, GTK_BUTTONS_OK, str);
    g_signal_connect_swapped(window, "response", G_CALLBACK(gtk_widget_destroy), window);
    gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(window));
}

bool settProfExists(const char *path)
{
    if(fileExists(path))
        return true;
    return false;
}

bool fileExists(const char *path)
{
    struct stat info;
    errno = 0;
    if((stat(path, &info)) != 0)
        if(errno == ENOENT)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: "Debug my code for me" isn't a good question. Start by eliminating superfluous details from your code until you reach a [mcve]. You may find the problem yourself along the way.

Comment: I see your function for creating the window, but I don't see any actual creation or destruction of any windows.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The "chooseProfName" is here just for completeness. It does create window that is constantly open in the loop. The loop is actualy in pickNameButtCB, running showError, where the dialog is created, and destroyed (I connected the "response" signal to widget destroying function).

Comment: @StoryTeller That's where you're wrong. I've been looking at this part of code for about 3 days now, 18 hours per day (yes, I've been doing nothing else but STARING at this code and trying to figure out what's wrong there). I'm asking "is it my fault or is it gtk's", not "debug my code for me" because according to gtk man pages and gtk memory managements guides etc. I've done nothing wrong.
Also, I think you're right about the code part. I'll remove unnecessary code from my post.

Comment: If you can't find the problem whilst eliminating clutter than by all means, post a question. But I suspect your lack of success thus far is highly affected by the amount of details.

Comment: That's not a [mcve] in your last edit. Seriously, take the time and reduce it (i.e. delete code) instead of being impatient.

Comment: Actually, according to the post you

Comment: (pressed enter instead of shift. sorry and edited for more than 5 minutes...) Actually, according to the post you linked it's ideal. The only thing that's missing is the parent window creation (which was mistakenly taken as the problem here, so I deleted it), and a while(1) showError( /* ... */); which is unnecessary I believe. If you're not happy with the amount of code that I deleted (which was just enough understand what the program here does) then well... noone's perfect. I'll try making it "just right" in a moment.

Comment: How did you measure the memory leak? And more importantly why have you not used the correct tools to do the measurement and find the source of the problem? Using G_SLICE=always-malloc on its own is not going to be of help to you. It is only useful when used with a tool to detect memory leaks.

Comment: Which GTK version and Windows version are you using ? That may help to know if that GTK version has known memory leaks.

Comment: @liberforce GTK 3.22.7-1 and Windows 10

Comment: @Errolvandel'Isle At first I just opened task manager and cycled through windows to see if the memory will grow infinitely or if it will stop at some point to just check if there's something wrong with the program's memory. Then I used Performance Manager to get more info about it.
So as you can see I didn't measure it - I just checked if there's something wrong with the memory I'm allocating, and concluded that it might be a memory leak.

Comment: @Errolvandel'Isle I didn't use valgrind because, well... it's not avaliable no Windows I believe. MSVC? Nah, I hate Micro$oft. Purifyplus or Insure++? I have no money (same for MSVC). And sadly there are no other tools that I know.

Comment: Ok, 3.22.7-1 is the latest GTK version for Windows provided by MSYS2 it seems. Could you please post a buildable example so it's possible to investigate a bit and try to reproduce ? As for Vagrind, AFAIK it's not available on Linux, but GTK is multiplatform, so you may build your code on linux and give valgrind a try.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is too incomplete to find the root cause.

This line especially is doesn't make sense. We're missing the definition of `entry` and you're trying to do several operations on the same line (`*entry = entryBase;`).

```
GList *entryBase = gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER(gtk_bin_get_child(GTK_BIN(window)))), *entry = entryBase;
```

The leak may however be in functions you call for which you don't provide the code (settProfExists, newProfile). So **please provide a minimal compilable example that reproduces the problem**.

As for the style, there are several errors: you're traversing a list the way you'd do with an array. See how is implemented GList and you'll see that this is silly (hint: look at `entry->prev` and `entry->next`):

```
   for(size_t i=g_list_length(entry); i>0 && !GTK_IS_ENTRY(entry->data); --i)
        entry = g_list_next(entry);
```

Then an architectural problem: don't try to inspect your UI to guess where are the widgets, just create a structure, and pass you `call` parameter and the GtkEntry you're interested in, in a structure with the gpointer data argument of the callback.

You should also not make paths by hand: you're using a fixed length array that may not be long enough. Use the portable `g_build_path` provided by the GLib (and free the path with `g_free` after use), that will handle for you Windows/Linux directories separators.

For your dialog, as you run `gtk_run_dialog`, you may just directly call gtk_destroy_widget afterwards instead of connecting a signal:

```
GtkWidget *window = gtk_message_dialog_new(parent, GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT, type, GTK_BUTTONS_OK, str);
gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(window));
gtk_widget_destroy(window);
```

Comment: Well... I'm not a fan of searching until NULL happens, but I think it would free one register, so gcc would have better optimization possibilities. Also, why inspecting GUI for something that I know is there is bad? I mean, is there much of a sense in creating a struct solely for displaying an entry dialog which will never be used again in the program?
As for `g_build_path`... it's a little too late now. I recently realized the power of GLib and will remember it once I start refactoring the project. And yes, I can just destroy widget instead connecting to a signal, thanks for that.

Comment: That's not only an optimization issue. Your code should not rely on how the UI is organized, so you can move widgets and improve the user experience without breaking your code.

Comment: As for the optimization, your example doesn't scale: on a UI with 100 elements in it, would traversing it still make sense? No. You shouldn't try to introspect the UI unless you really have a good reason to do so (like writing an introspection tool like gtk-inspector). Also "premature optimization is the root of all evil". Just the call to `g_list_length` traverses the *whole* list once, then you traverse it a second time in your loop. Don't think at the register level unless you're sure your algorithm is optimal.